# Swipe between pages doesn't work and unable two fingers scrolling up/down

Tags: safari, trackpad, firefox, web-browsing, web-browser

Since this morning, the "swipe between pages" functionality doesn't work anymore on my computer!

**Web-browser specific description of the problem**

*Google Chrome*

When I try to swipe between pages on Google Chrome, it just does not work. The window get shifted within its frame and come back to its original position.

*Safari*

When I try to swipe between pages on Safari, the window slightly shifts within its frame and get stuck into this position. Further two-finger movements (including scrolling up and down) are then not functioning. When I open a new window, the scrolling up/down is working again.

*Firefox*

When I try to swipe between pages on Firefox, nothing happen and further two-finger movements (including scrolling up and down) are then not functioning. When I open a new window, the scrolling up/down is working again.

**How I tried to solve this issue**

I opened system preferences to make sure that in the section trackpad, the option swipe between pages is activated. Yes, it is activated!

For some reason, I checked the `always` box next to `Show scroll bars` in the general section in the system preferences.

In Bash, I wrote the following command line: `defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scrollBehavior 2` but nothing happens!

Comment: If the system does not accept your settings, then try to repair the permissions in disk utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging out and back in.

I know that sounds like a "grasping at straws"-type solution, but this is the sort of doesn't-make-sense kind of problem that I've seen fixed by logging out (or maybe even restarting).

Comment: Why didn't I try that before? That solved my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

What worked as well for me was switching off two finger swipe from the trackpad settings ('Swipe between pages' setting), then turning it on again directly after. A lot more convenient than logging out and in again.

[image: Swipe between pages setting]

If the problem happens too often a PRAM reset often helps as well:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard:
   Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down
   simultaneously in step 4.
3. Turn on the computer.
4. Press and hold the
   Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears. Hold the
   keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound
   for the second time.
5. Release the keys.

Comment: This worked. Only changing to 3-finger swipe and back was not enough, the checkbox must be unchecked and then checked again.

Comment: wow i can't believe this actually worked.  checkbox must be unchecked and then checked again.